# How can I use Pymongo Aggregation to inquiry this dataset?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is my first time use MongoDB aggregation query. The dataset I have is as follow:

```
{ // doc 1
    "_id" : ObjectId("55f2481bc9b4cd1c0c198c9f"),
    "channels" : [ 
        "channel_3", 
        "channel_2", 
        "channel_1", 
        "channel_4"
    ],
    "msd" : 25,
    "uid" : "000012bb-2e5a-8bd3-d36a-fa037973e632"
}
{ // doc 2
    "_id" : ObjectId("55f2481bc9b4cd123452345f"),
    "channels" : [ 
        "channel_3", 
        "channel_4"
    ],
    "msd" : 50,
    "uid" : "000012bb-2e5a-8bd3-d36a-fa037973e632"
}
{ // doc 3
    "_id" : ObjectId("55f2481bc9b4cd1c0c198c9f"),
    "channels" : [  
        "channel_2"
    ],
    "msd" : 100,
    "uid" : "000012bb-2e5a-8bd3-d36a-fa037973e632"
}
{ // doc 4
    "_id" : ObjectId("55f2481bc9b4cd1c0c198c9f"),
    "channels" : [  
        "channel_2"
    ],
    "msd" : 80,
    "uid" : "000012bb-2e5a-8bd3-d36a-fa037973e632"
}
```

I have built a compound index:

```
userlog.create_index([('uid', ASCENDING), ('channels', ASCENDING)])
```

Now, **given a user and an array of channels, I want to retrieve the average of msd whose at least one channel is in the query channels.**
For instance, a query is:

```
{"uid" : "000012bb-2e5a-8bd3-d36a-fa037973e632", "channels" : ["channel_1", "channel_2"], }
```

The channels of doc 1 contains "channel_1" and "channel_2" and the channels of doc 3 and 4 contains "channels_2". So the expected return value is (25+100+80)/3 = 68.33

**====================== TRIAL 1 =======================**

CODE:

```
pipe=[ 
    {"$unwind":'$channels'},
    {"$match":{'uid':"000012bb-2e5a-8bd3-d36a-fa037973e632", 'channels':{'$in':channels}}},
    {"$group":{'_id': '$channels', 'averageMSD':{'$avg':'$msd'}}}
    ]

for res in db.aggregate(pipeline=pipe):
    print(res)
```

RESULT:

```
{'_id': 'channel_1', 'averageMSD': 25.0}
{'_id': 'channel_2', 'averageMSD': 68.33333333333333}
```

It seems that "$unwind" makes the doc 1 is unexpectedly counted twice. Also, "$unwind" is quite slow.

**====================== TRIAL 2 =======================**

CODE:

```
pipe=[ 
    {"$match":{'uid':"000012bb-2e5a-8bd3-d36a-fa037973e632", 'channels':{'$in':channels}}},
    {"$group":{'_id': '$channels', 'averageMSD':{'$avg':'$msd'}}}
    ]

for res in db.aggregate(pipeline=pipe):
    print(res)
```

RESULT:

```
{'averageMSD': 90.0, '_id': ['channel_2']}
{'averageMSD': 25.0, '_id': ['channel_3', 'channel_2', 'channel_1', 'channel_4']}
```

The result is still not what I want. It seems that I should not group the result by "channels". But I do not how I can fix it.

How can I use aggregation to inquire the DB efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
pipe=[ 
    {"$match":{'uid':"000012bb-2e5a-8bd3-d36a-fa037973e632", 'channels':{'$in':channels}}},
    {"$group":{'_id': None, 'averageMSD':{'$avg':'$msd'}}}
    ]
```